# Emphasis sentence? How to interpret this sentence? (With ~)

Tags: emphasis

I am very sorry for the ambiguous title. But I don't know how to explain it.

> With no artist in any art form is the life equivalent to the work, exactly; still, each informs the other, and the illumination of the dynamic between them is the biographer`s job.

I tried to understand the meaning of this sentence, especially the first phrase. (With no artist in any art form is the life equivalent to the work)

I can't find what is a subject and what is a verb. I kinda heard that this sentence is something like emphasis sentence, but I can analyze the first phrase.

Could you let me know how to interpret it? And could you tell me what should I study to understand this grammar?

Comment: A rephrasing would be: "The life is exactly equivalent to the work with no artist in any art form."  That's indicating that no matter what art form an artist works in (not just biographers), their work doesn't portray the life of their subject exactly as it is.

Comment: In the first clause, the subject is *life* and the verb is *is* – or some might say the verb is *is equivalent to*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is no artist, [working] in any art form, whose life is exactly equivalent to their work.* The writer says that, nevertheless, the life and the work influence one another, and it is the biographer's job to show how this happens.

The order of words makes the sentence rather convoluted. The only way to get used to this style of writing is to read widely.